# GAE webapp alternative working outside of GAE environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

I like working with GAE environment as well as with its webapp framework. I am creating a web application using GAE environment. What I think about is how to create a version of my application that could run in another environment, like some other hosting or cloud service the easiest way. I know I will have to think about database storage alternative too and some other features that GAE gives and is not available on another platform out of the box. But now I wonder just about webapp framework. So, what can I use as alternative to this in GAE? May be some existing framework that is as much as possible close to GAE webapp? I know it is using webob, may be somebody has already implemented this alternative? Please give me some advice. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing about webapp that is specifically tied to App Engine - you could continue to use webapp, if you wished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-release version of [Tipfy](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/) is adding the ability to be used outside of App Engine.

Also, you might want to consider instead of finding a web framework that works in multiple environments, try out a way to run App Engine apps in other environments with something like [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/), or [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/), in my opinion it's a great and well documented web framework and it offers a powerful [Dal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer) that allows your application to be portable among different types of database, GAE datastore included <sup>*</sup>.

<sup>* with some limitation explained [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11#Database-Issues)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Pyramid. [Running Pyramid on Google App Engine](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/tutorials/gae/index.html)

Like you mentioned, SQLAlchemy doesn't work on GAE and you won't be able to use the same data storage routines. Depending on what you are doing, you could design your application so that most everything else would be interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be Django-nonrel.  It's a version of Django that will work on app engine and is designed to make it easy to port your code from app engine to other platforms.

[Running Pure Django Projects on Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a couple GAE applications, and have come to feel that [Django Nonrel](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html) is a little too heavy for my tastes. I really like the ease-of-use of [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), and I'd expect you'd feel the same way — especially for simple apps.

[Here's one GAE Flask skeleton](https://github.com/blossom/flask-gae-skeleton).

[Here's another](https://github.com/jugyo/flask-gae-template).

You could also check out [tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few projects thats are working on replicating the GAE environment:

[Typhoon AE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/)

[App Scale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/)

I have not personally used either of these but I think that would be the best place to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Series about using Google App Engine with some Python web frameworks](http://www.franciscosouza.com/tag/google-app-engine/) by [franciscosouza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547879/francisco-souza)